# Конструктор копирования и целостность указателей

Tags: ооп, указатели, c++, конструктор

У меня есть класс Stream, одним из членов которого является вектор объектов класса Request. Элементы вектора создаются в конструкторе класса Stream, причем одним из полей класса Request является указатель на родительский объект класса Stream.
При копировании объектов класса Stream указатели в объектах Request "ломаются": они почему-то указывают на объекты Stream, в которых вектор объектов Request пуст. Насколько я понимаю, это происходит потому, что стандартный конструктор копирования не заботится о сохранности указателей.
Как написать свой конструктор копирования, в котором внутри вызывается стандартный конструктор копирования (чтобы не писать код присвоения каждого члена)? Или как иначе можно решить проблему сохранности указателей?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Исходя из названия, вам не нужен конструктор копирования. Копировать `Stream` обычно не имеет смысла, так как это скорее всего приведёт к хаосу при попытке писать в поток из двух экземпляров.

Наоборот, вам нужно запретить копирование. Для этого в свежих версиях компилятора просто допишите внутри класса

```
Stream(const Stream&) = delete;
```

---

Если вы всё же хотите построить копирующий конструктор, вам нужно, по идее, просто скопировать вектор:

```
class Stream
{
    vector<Request> requests;
public:
    Stream(const Stream& s) : requests(s.requests)
    {
    }
};
```

Но! Чтобы это правильно работало, у вас обязан быть правильный конструктор копирования в `Request`.

---

Если новые `Request`-объекты должны знать о новом `Stream`, вам придётся поизвращаться:

```
class Stream
{
    vector<Request> requests;
public:
    Stream(const Stream& s) :
        requests(s.requests.size()) // выделяем место, не копируем
    {
        for (auto& req : s.requests)
            requests.emplace_back(Request(req, this));
            // создаём новые реквесты, указывающие на *этот* стрим
    }
};
```

---

Если я не ошибаюсь, можно опустить `Request` в `emplace_back`:

```
            requests.emplace_back(req, this);
```

Будет вызван соответствующий конструктор.

Comment: Мне нужно копирование. Но мне как-то необходимо переназначить указатели на новый объект.

Comment: @DarkGenius: А какой usecase? Для чего именно оно вам нужно?

Comment: @VladD:
У меня создается вектор объектов класса Stream. Когда я добавляю объект в вектор с помощью функции push_back, происходит копирование объекта.

Comment: @DarkGenius: Это чисто техническая проблема, которую вы почему-то решаете не с той стороны. Вопрос в том, имеет ли смысл копирование `Stream`'а. Я бы, допустим, завёл `vector<Stream*>` или например `vector<shared_ptr<Stream>>`.

Comment: @VladD: Да, теперь я понимаю, что так лучше сделать. Но у меня чисто теоретический интерес остался, как решить проблему в моем случае.

Comment: @DarkGenius: Обновил ответ.

Comment: @VladD: Спасибо большое! Благодаря вашему ответу я открыл для себя функцию emplace_back. Насколько я понимаю, её использование вместо push_back для заполнения vector<Stream> само по себе решает описанную проблему, так как копирования в этом случае не будет.

Comment: @DarkGenius: Пожалуйста!

Учтите, что `emplace_back` не спасает от необходимости правильно определить конструктор копирования: как только `count()` догонит `capacity()`, при добавлении следующего элемента все элементы скопируются на новое место, используя всё тот же конструктор копирования.

Поэтому, может быть, всё же стоит подумать о переделке в `vector` указателей.

Answer (score 1):

> Как написать свой конструктор копирования, в котором внутри вызывается стандартный конструктор копирования (чтобы не писать код присвоения каждого члена)?

---

> у меня чисто теоретический интерес остался, как решить проблему в моем случае.

Просто до безобразия. Добавьте к структуре данных дополнительный **базовый** класс (base), члены которого должны быть скопированы автоматически. В **наследуемом** от базового (derivative) оставьте члены, копирование которых должно быть под контролем. После этого в констукторе можно дописать в список инициализации:

```
derivative( const derivative&src ) : base( src ){
  ...
}
```

Все члены из базового класса будут скопированы автоматически.

P.S. Аналогично задача решается и в операторе присваивания (дополнительным "кастом" `this` к базовому).

Answer (score 0):

> Как написать свой конструктор копирования, в котором внутри вызывается стандартный конструктор копирования

Если не ошибаюсь, то вызов одного конструктора из другого реализован только в C++14, в более ранних стандартах языка этот трюк не сработает (код скомпилируетcя, запустится, но не будет работать, как вы того ожидаете).

> чтобы не писать код присвоения каждого члена

Конструктор копирования, генерируемый компилятором, выполняет только т.н. поверхностное копирование, т.е., в отношении данных, он копирует только указатели на переменные-члены объекта класса). И если вы хотите полностью контролировать этот процесс, то вам необходимо самим реализовать конструктор копирования и "руками" скопировать все нужные вам элементы.